# Django retrieve get_foo_value within values_list and annotate query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I Have Written A Query that returns (rating, count)

```
result = list(Film.objects.values_list('rating').annotate(count=Count('rating')))
```

rating is a choice field of

```
rating = (
        ("5","Excellent"),
        ("4","Good"),
        ("3","Average"),
        ("2","Bad"),
        ("1","Very Bad"),
    )
```

I currently get the result like this

```
[(5, 10), (4,8), (3,7), (2,1), (1,4)]
```

I wish to get the pairs like this

```
[("Excellent",10),("Good",8)...]
```

Is there anything I can do within the Query to get it ? Whats the best method to get the desired result ?

Something like get_foo_display within this one.

Comment: `annotate()` performs on database level and in database `rating` stored as *integer* (or char as per your model definition)

Comment: It is stored as 1 2 3 4 5 I'm aware of that, what I need the Corresponding display value, like get_FOO_display would give output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) `Function` to achieve this below.

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, When
Film.objects.annotate(proxy_rating=Case(
    When(rating=5, then="Excellent"),
    When(rating=4, then="Good"),
    When(rating=3, then="Average"),
    When(rating=2, then="Bad"),
    When(rating=1, then="Very Bad"),
    output_field=CharField()     
    )).values_list("proxy_rating").annotate(count=Count('rating'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any Ideas to change this into an ordered List ?

Comment: Ordered list based on rating like excellent followed by good like that?

Comment: Yes, Excellent, good.. to Very Bad and maybe Very Bad, Bad.. to Excellent. Basically any custom order.

Comment: I think it's better to to put that logic in code than db., Else try to do order_by ("rating") before .annotate(proxy_rating)